# saving highscore scores to mobile phone

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a game with a highscore table in Air for Android but I need the score to save on to the phone. So far I have the working scoreboard in the Emulator. My code is below:

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;

var scoreArray: Array = new Array();
dg_score.addColumn("Name");
dg_score.addColumn("Score");
tf_name.text = "Enter name here";

function addScore(evt:MouseEvent)
{
var scoreObj:Object = new Object();
scoreObj["Name"] = tf_name.text;
scoreObj["Score"] = counter.text;
//each time object is added, it is pushed to end of array 
scoreArray.push (scoreObj);
//sorted by the score column, in descending order
scoreArray.sortOn("Score", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
dg_score.dataProvider = new DataProvider(scoreArray);


}
```

Does anyone know how I would do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#includeExamplesSummary) class to save the data to your phone

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myScoresObject");
mySharedObject.data.name = name;
mySharedObject.data.score = score;
mySharedObject.flush();
```

Once this is done initially `SharedObject.getLocal("myScoresObject");` will return with the saved scores.